# How to add svn plugin in eclipse

Tags: java

Been trying very hard to add SVN repository to my Rational Application Developer using the following URL.
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/4.0/update-site/

However every time I try to install the new software I get this error message..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZq51.png)

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Comment: What does "Details" show?

Comment: Pretty long message. When I click details it shows this,

Comment: An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=IBM Software Delivery Platform_3 com.ibm.sdp.eclipse.ide, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.commons.httpclient,3.1.0.v201012070820
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.commons.io,2.2.0.v201405211200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.ws.commons.util,1.0.1.v20100518-1140

Comment: Tried that like 10 years back. Meaning: we used RAD, mainly for UML modelling, and wanted to store the model files in our SVN source code repo. Just never got it to work. Honestly, you are asking for trouble here. My recommendation: try to work around. Meaning: any current day IDE works **much** better with git than with SVN. And: there are means to "wrap" a git repo around a SVN repo: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn

Comment: That is what we did in the end: we used git-svn ... so that yes, the backend was a SVN repo, storing our data. But on our local machines, it looked like an ordinary git clone. That worked sooooo much better for us.

Comment: If that isnt an option for you ... in the end RAD and websphere are commercial products by IBM, so I assume that you/your company is paying for it. Then: bug their support. It is rather unlikely that you will get a good answer here. RAD is a big, complex product, and no outsider has a clear understanding what exactly is going on in their pre-canned version of Eclipse.